# how to arrange product in order for website woocommerce , EX; product er07, er08, er09, er10, er11 . NOT er er10, er101, er111

Tags: sorting, woocommerce

I have over 2000 sku product. When I sort the items by name , it would sort correctly up to 10 and skip.

EX:
ER01, ER02, ER03, ER04, ER05,ERO6,ER07,ER08,ER09,ER10,ER101,ER102.

I NEED IT TO BE

ER01, ER02, ER03, ER04, ER05,ERO6,ER07,ER08,ER09,ER10,ER11,ER12.

ER stands for earring, I also have P - PENDANT, B - BANGLES, R - RINGS ETC...

PLEASE HELP.
THANKS IN ADVANCE

I have tried plugins but it messed up my whole site.
I have not tried any code attempt.

[photo added of how the number are skipping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSaCx.jpg)

Comment: U want to sort by sku or title ?

Comment: @Snuffy i want to add title

Comment: You would need custom meta that later to use for sorting. The reason is that alphabetical sorting treats numbers as characters, so "10" would come before "2" because it compares each character from left to right. Also Woo have sorting number for each product that you can use for sorting too.